# What datatype is the Exception variable?

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception

I have a code running where I need to save the exceptions into a SQL Server database using the following code:

```
    public void AcieveSomething()
    {
       //Datatype Declarations 
        string ApplicationName = "App_Name";
        string ClassName = "Class_Name";
        string MethodName = "Achieve Something";

       try
       {
         //Main part of the code
       }

       catch(Exception ex)
       {
         //Calling function to input the error into DB
          ErrorLog.WriteErrorLog(ex, ApplicationName, ClassName, MethodName);
       }
   }
```

If I'm going to put the `ex` value into DB, what is the datatype for `Exception ex;` in SQL Server database ?

Comment: Mainly you should get the message, innerException and stackTrace

Comment: 1) SSMS isn't a database; it's a tools for connecting to SQL Server databases 2) There's not a direct SQL-equivalent for every .NET type. Instead, you should break the exception down to it's relevant parts, e.g. the name of the exception type (`ex.GetType().Name`), message (`ex.Message`), etc.

Comment: You can use exception message to store in database. By using message method.(ex.Message or ex.InnerException)

Comment: There is no data type for exception in MS SQL DB. The best data type you can assign to it would be [n]vahrach(max) or text. Object type Ecpetion can have an infinite number of inner exceptions and the stack trace can become very large. Therefore you have to make it a large text field. Just remember you should store more than ex.Message as that might not be enough to find the exception. At the very least you have to use ex.ToString() but you must try to extract as much information as possible form the exception before logging it to the db

Comment: @p.s.w.g Sorry for the misdirection, what i meant was SQL Server databases

Comment: @Sarbanjeet and p.s.w.g : What if need to ex.Message or ex.InnerException into a table in my DB, then what is the datatype I must use in SQL ?

Comment: @Sarbanjeet If you're storing the `Exception`, you should always use `ex.ToString()` to capture the exception message and stack trace, and do the same for any inner exceptions you may run into. Walk down the path until you've retrieved all inner exceptions, and store them as a string in your DB.

Comment: @SandySands Yes, It should be stored as string. i agree with you aevitas.

Comment: @aevitas: I'll do that. Thanks

Comment: To trace information you have to store these informations in order. 1> InnerException, 2> Message, 3> StackTrace, 4> Source. And store it in single string by separating with ## in single column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Liath said, `Exception` inherits from `System.Object`. Any error or warning coming back from the database will usually be of the type `SqlException`.

A good ideal would be to serialize the `Exception` object to XML and store it as XML in the database.

To do this, it's best to create your own `Exception` type that encapuslates the information that you want to store, something like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class StorableException
{
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string StackTrace { get; set; }

    public StorableException()
    {
        this.TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public StorableException(string Message) : this()
    {
        this.Message = Message;
    }

    public StorableException(System.Exception ex) : this(ex.Message)
    {
        this.StackTrace = ex.StackTrace;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Message + this.StackTrace;
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    StorableException s = new StorableException(ex);

    //now we can serialize it
    XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StorableException));
    StringWriter sww = new StringWriter();
    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww);
    xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, s);
    var xml = sww.ToString();

    //now save the xml file to a column in your database

    ErrorLog.WriteErrorLog(ex, ApplicationName, ClassName, MethodName);
}
```

Comment: I don't know why the downvote!? This is a good suggestion, it captures all the properties, handles inner exceptions and works as the Exception class is serialisable.

Comment: @Liath No idea about the downvote lol, maybe it was the Grinch :)

Comment: The question is _What datatype is the exception_. Not how to save in the db. However you are correctly suggesting the better approach at its task. Not mine downvote though. If you just add some code example and an explanation why he/she should use a string.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin I've added code include both serialization of the exception to XML and encapsulation of required information into a new exception

Comment: @mattytommo: Thank you, this has been very helpful. Would it help if I included the first part of the code into DLL class ?

Comment: @SandySands No problems glad I could help. Yeah it'd put it into a function in a class elsewhere so you can call it elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @Liath I'm sorry, it is a good solution, but where does he handle inner exceptions? I have some methods of my own to handle exceptions and I can't see where in the code he's doing that. He's getting the current exception's message and stacktrace, that's it, right? Am I missing something? Please clarify, as I'm interested in understanding how this would work...

Answer (score 3):

[Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a class which inherits from `System.Object`, if you want to persist it to a database you'll  need to decide which properties you want to store and add them to different columns (or use the serialised approach in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27599295/352176)).

Typically the properties developers use are Message, StackTrace and InnerException although other types which derive from Exception may have others.

Both Message and StackTrace are strings so an nvarchar (or other text field) would be suitable for storing them. As InnerException is another exception (and may have it's own inner exception) the best way would be to add the InnerException as it's own row in your exceptions table.

Comment: What if need to ex.Message or ex.InnerException into a table in my DB, then what is the datatype I must use in SQL ?

Comment: @SandySands see edits, message is a string so nvarchar(x) or any other data type designed for handling text

Comment: @SandySands no problem - if this has answered your question please mark it as accepted using the large tick.

Answer (score 0):

When serializing the Exception as XML into the database, it makes it a pain to query back. Writing the Exception.InnerException to a nvarchar(max) is more convenient.